# Why MIT lecture breadth-first search algorithm is so complicated?

Tags: breadth-first-search

I watched a [video for BFS from MIT](http://https:://youtu.be/s-CYnVz-uh4) and the algorithm the lecturer presented was really complicated compared to what I came up. My solution seems to work fine and walk through the vertices in the correct order. Am I missing something?

```
public static void BFS(GraphNode currentNode, GraphNode searchedNode) {
    if (currentNode.index == searchedNode.index) {
        System.out.println("Found!");
        return;
    }

    if (visited[currentNode.index]) {
        return;
    }

    visited[currentNode.index] = true;

    for (GraphNode child : currentNode.children) {
        if (!visited[child.index]) {
            nodeQueue.add(child);
        }
    }

    if (!nodeQueue.isEmpty()) {
        BFS(nodeQueue.poll(), searchedNode);
    }
}
```

One drawback is that it keeps running after finding a node, but that could be fixed easily by clearing the queue when element is found.

Comment: Could you link to the video of MIT?

Comment: Your algorithm will make at least one function call per node. With a large enough graph, the stack will overflow. The compiler might apply a tail-recursive optimisation (which would generally avoid this issue), just don't presume that it would be applied.

Comment: @Kain0_0 I understand, thank you for the explanation :) I will explore the algorithm from MIT as I suppose it is always good to learn how things work.

Comment: @STanja Here you go: https://youtu.be/s-CYnVz-uh4

Comment: Thanks! Added inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is best handled by contacting the lecturer, but here are four reasons.

A Kain0_0 remarks, your solution is recursive, while his isn't.

Didactic considerations behind this might be:

1. Recursion is hard for some students. Perhaps it hasn't been taught at this point in the course, or is considered an unnecessary burden.
2. Most BFS implementations in practice do not use recursion. Programmers need to spot algorithms in other peoples' code all the time. There is value in presenting algorithms in their most common form.

Furthermore,

3. You're sweeping some stuff under the carpet. He makes his data structures explicit, because he wants to show how much time and space his algorithm uses. You don't: you leave the recursive call stack implicit, and you don't show how `.children` and `.index` are represented or created.
4. He's doing more. He can report the level at which the node was found. You don't keep that information.